# How to set a scrollbar's width in ListView in WinRT?

Tags: xaml, listview, styles, windows-runtime, scrollbar

I have a ListView control in WinRT platform, but its scrollbar is smaller than I want. I want to make it bigger than the default style one. How should I create the style and apply it? I follow this thread [How to apply WPF ScrollBar style to a particular listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163259/how-to-apply-wpf-scrollbar-style-to-a-particular-listview) , but it can't affect the scrollbar on my side. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to in the design view of your form right click the ListView, click Edit Template/Edit a Copy, hit OK.
Then you have to do the same for the ScrollViewer that is part of the ListView template - this is a little bit more tricky because when you right click it - you will get the ItemsPresenter to select, so you will need to hit Esc to select the outer control which is the ScrollViewer and make sure you right click just its border, so you can edit the template of the ScrollViewer. Then you have to do the same to the vertical ScrollBar... And then you have to set the widths of all elements and the heights of the top and bottom RepeatButtons to the values you want. Then change the padding on the ListView to account for the wider ScrollBar (maybe there's a better way), generally fiddle with the templates. It does not have a simple property to control it all. [Here's a sample](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1192076/App55.zip) (sorry, the templates are rather verbose and don't fit in a SO answer.

Comment: Cheers, Filip. I followed your description. It works fine on my side. The template stuff is very verbose as you said. Thanks again.